# How to Bind an Observable collection in Autocomplete Text box?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

I need to bind an Observable collection to my AutoComplete Text box in the WPF application. But When I run the application after binding in the designer, I got a display with my full BL class Reference in the dropdown. How to avoid this behaviour? Also I want to show some other properties in the dropdown(as details view) and I should be able to get the Other properties of the object once I select a item from the List. Is anybody can come with a code snippet?

Comment: Are you using the inbuilt AutoComplete text box from wpf toolkit or .Net 4.0 framework? Or are you creating it as your own?

Comment: Yes I am using the inbuilt AutoCompleteBox from WPF toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `ItemTemplate` property in the `AutoCompleteTextBox`. You can use that to display whatever you want in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I'm assuming your ObservableCollection is a user defined object and you're binding the ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection and not providing a DataTemplate. The controls within the DataTemplate would then be bound to the public properties of the object stored in the ObservableCollection.

The DataTemplate would also allow for you to show all the properties you want in the dropdown listbox.  Since I'm unaware of the auto-complete textbox you are using I can't really give an example of the DataTemplate.

Here is a simple example of a ListBox DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is a link which will give you all the info you need:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx.

Comment: After defining a item template, It is now working. Thanks for both Josh and AngelWPF. <Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>